# Why does this Task.Factory.FromAsync call not work?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I created the following sample to wrap my head around the usage of Task.Factory.FromAsync. According to the docs a syntax like this should be working, but besides it compiling just fine it's always returning 0 bytes, whilst the built in ReadAsync works perfectly fine. Does anyone know why it doesn't work the way i'd expect it to?

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        await await Task.WhenAny(
            Task.Run(async() => await WriteStream(stream)),
            Task.Run(async() => await ReadStream(stream)));
    }

    private static async Task ReadStream(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            // this version does not work
            var read = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(stream.BeginRead, stream.EndRead, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null);
            // this version works
//          var read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer,0, buffer.Length);
            if(read == 0)
                continue;

            Console.WriteLine($"bytes read: {read}.");
            Console.WriteLine($"message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Trim((char)0)}.");
            Console.WriteLine($"Waiting to receive bytes...");
        }
    }

    private static async Task WriteStream(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for keyboard input.");
        while (Console.ReadLine() is var input && input != "x")
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for keyboard input.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way this code is written, race conditions are guaranteed. If you reverse the order of the reader and writer tasks you'll see that `await stream.ReadAsync()` stops working too

Comment: You've not implemented any kind of synchronisation mechanism (such as events) to coordinate between your producer and consumer. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: MemoryStream is just a Stream interface on top of a buffer. There aren't any real asynchronous operations in this case. [MemoryStream.ReadAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,375) simply returns the requested data with `Task.FromResult`. It doesn't have `BeginRead/EndRead` methods. Those are provided by the base [Stream](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,305) class which goes and fires off a background operation of its own

Comment: In effect, your code [writes *synchronously*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,557). When you call `ReadAsync` it will also read synchronously. What it returns though depends on the stream's current position. Writing moves that position which means that `ReadAsync` can only return the correct data by accident - if it tries to read data *before* `WriteAsync` had a change to update the Position

Comment: Calling `BeginRead` starts *another* background job, inside the `ReadStream` job that was already running in the background due to the `Task.Run` call.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos with ReadAsync it does work though. I'd be curious how to write the Task.Factory.FromAsync call to make it work similarly to the other call

Comment: @Dbl only by chance as I explained. Reverse the order and it fails. As I explained, and as the source code shows, that's a *synchronous* operation. It's a Read followed by a `return Task.FromResult()`.

Comment: @Dbl you *can't* write this code correctly without adding synchronization between the reader and writer. Streams aren't thread-safe.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok so essentially what you're saying is that the reason this isn't working is purely down to the stream i've picked here and the way i interact with it and that the FromAsync would work fine otherwise? I merely did this sample in order to verify it works before using it in production code. Feel free to post it as an answer.